# autosizing a uitextview in a uitableviewcell when rotating

Tags: autoresizingmask

I have a pretty straightforward UITableView that contains a fixed label on the left side and  then a UITextField in each cell.  I need the uitextfield to expand and contract its width with the cell when the device rotates.  I've tried setting

autoresizesSubviews = YES;
autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

for the tableview, the cell and the cell.contentView and it none of them seem to affect the textField.

And when I set the autoresizingMask of the actual textField to flexibleWidth and FlexibleRightMargin then the textField extends far off the screen no matter what orientation it's in.

Here's the code where I create the textField and add it to the cell:

```
    int marginBetweenCellAndScreenEdge;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    marginBetweenCellAndScreenEdge = 44;
} else {
    marginBetweenCellAndScreenEdge = 10;
}

float viewWidth = self.parentViewController.view.bounds.size.width;
int textFieldWidth = viewWidth - (2*marginBetweenCellAndScreenEdge) - 75 - 20;
NSLog(@"%d", textFieldWidth);

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, textFieldWidth, 25)];
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
[textField setDelegate:self];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.tag = kTextFieldTag;

textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


//make it so that the UITextField subview resigns the firstresponder (keyboard) when done editing
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!  Thanks!!